# Sci-fi novel in the 90's or early 2000 - Girl revived in violet room, tried to escape

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, soft-sci-fi

In the early 2000s I read a Science fiction book in school. The details I remember are vague. Just little glimpses of the beginning.
I believe in the beginning of the book a girl, the protagonist, wakes up in a kind of Laboratory out of a deep sleep. She doesn't know why she is there or what she is wearing. The room is glowing a type of violet. She realizes something is wrong and tries to escape. The room should be filled with other people like herself too I think.
I think she ends up being on a space ship. 
Can't remember the middle or ending though.

It has had a little place in my mind for so long. want to read it again.